# Passing List of objects to ASP.Net Core MVC controller using jQuery AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core

I Know this is a repeated question but I can't find out what I'm doing wrong. Following is my code

My Model

```
public class DivisionDetails
    {
        public int DivisionId { get; set; }
        public string DivisionName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? UpdatedOn { get; set; }
        public string FormattedUpdatedOn
        {
            get
            {
                return GetFormattedDate();
            }
        }

        private string GetFormattedDate()
        {
            return UpdatedOn.HasValue ? UpdatedOn.Value.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") : "";
        }
    }
```

my jQuery

```
var divisions=[];
        var item = {};

                item.DivisionName ="polo"
                item.DivisionId = 1;
                item.UpdatedOn = null;

                divisions.push(item);

   var itemTwo = {};

                item.DivisionName ="polo2"
                item.DivisionId = 2;
                item.UpdatedOn = null;

                divisions.push(itemTwo);

 var items = JSON.stringify({ "divisions":divisions });

success= function(data){
alert(data);
}

           $.ajax({
                url: "url",
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                data:items,
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: "json",
                success: success
            });
```

my controller

```
public IActionResult Save(List<DivisionDetails> divisions)
        {
            var result = _divisionService.Save(divisions);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

When the call hit the controller I'm getting an empty list. Please point me to the right direction

Comment: @hasan tried that not working

Comment: I have updated my answer and I missed the point that you dont use [FromBody] in controller method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `[FromBody]` to get list object in controller side.

Also you fill `item` object twice therefore `itemTwo` object becomes null.

```
var divisions=[];

var item = {};
item.DivisionName ="polo"
item.DivisionId = 1;
item.UpdatedOn = null;

divisions.push(item);

var itemTwo = {};
itemTwo.DivisionName ="polo2"
itemTwo.DivisionId = 2;
itemTwo.UpdatedOn = null;

divisions.push(itemTwo);


public IActionResult Save([FromBody]List<DivisionDetails> divisions)
{
    var result = _divisionService.Save(divisions);
    return Json(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a  lot man [FromBody] was the missing piece. You just made my day